# How do I change cursor size on hover in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, cursor

I'm trying to change cursor size on hovering h1 in css, without using js and .gif cursors

```
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="header">text here</h1>
</div>

<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Here's css

```
.cursor {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    border: 1px solid #ebe8e8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.header:hover + .cursor {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(8);
}
```

Why is it not working?..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase cursor size in HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351916/increase-cursor-size-in-html-body)

Answer (score 1):

```
.header:hover .cursor {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(8);
}
```

Comment: from the question, it seems like he has a custom cursor created with html `<div class="cursor"></div>` so to increase the size on hover, he has to use the proper css selector that will target the above element...