# CSS cursor size while entering text field

Tags: html, css

How to adjust the size of cursor when you click inside the input, i want my cursor height bigger than text's.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase cursor size in HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351916/increase-cursor-size-in-html-body)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.