# How to change Cursor image on another image hover using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, z-index

I am working on a task where I hover on an image, I should get a custom cursor(150x150).
I do workarounds, but am unable to get a smooth hover. Please help me with this.

```
[https://codepen.io/LeelaMathaiyan/pen/yLjgWjK][1]
```

Sample screenshot on hovering an image using image cursor:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without js, just:

```
.class {
    cursor: url('components/assets/decorations/Pointer.png'), auto;
  }
```

in you css.

Of course, if you need to do it dynamically, you can use the tag style.

Comment: As I mentioned , the cursor image size is 150px X 150px. We couldn't able to apply thru css. We have to achieve thru js by capturing the cursor co-ordinates.

Comment: I just used a picture of the appropriate size

Comment: , we have to apply an image with (15x150)size.

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351916/increase-cursor-size-in-html-body

Comment: For this question, I couldn't be able to achieve thru js. I just reduced the size of the image and apply thru css. Thanks Much for the answers. @Gibloor